# AlarmManager or Broadcast receiver battery widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

Which solution is better for Battery widget.  Broadcast receiver or AlarmManager trigered every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends upon your definition of "better".

You cannot register for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcasts from the manifest, so you would have to have a service running *all the time* that manages a dynamically-registered receiver for this broadcast. Many users dislike this.

`AlarmManager` avoids the need for the continuously-running service, but it will mean that your app widget will lag a bit on finding out of battery level changes. However, you could allow the user to control the polling frequency, via a `SharedPreference`, rather than hard-coding it to be five minutes. That way, the user is in control over how much CPU/battery is consumed by your app from the polling, and therefore is in control over how much lag there will be.